# obtain xml info from URL

Tags: xml, api

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/MadMimi.class.php');

$mailer = new MadMimi('xx@xx.org', 'API');   
$file = ""http://madmimi.com/audience_lists/lists.xml";

$xml=simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

I am trying to connect to a madmimi API but the code is giving me the error: cannot create object. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put `https://api.madmimi.com/audience_members.xml?username=XXXXXX&api_key=XXXXXXXX`
in the url to make it work. 
Thanks to madmimi support for their quick response.